# Unrelated visible overload of || prevents || from short-circuiting in a requires-clause

Tags: c++, clang, c++20

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Disjunctions) says:

> Disjunctions are evaluated left to right and short-circuited (if the left constraint is satisfied, template argument substitution into the right constraint is not attempted).

This appears to be correct, because following code compiles:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    static constexpr bool value = T::value;
};

template <typename T>
void foo() requires (sizeof(T) == 1) || A<T>::value {}

int main()
{
    foo<char>();
}
```

Even though `A<char>::value` is ill-formed, there's no error because it's short-circuited away.

But if I add an unrelated overload of `operator||`, it stops working:

```
struct Dummy {};
bool operator||(Dummy, Dummy) {return true;}

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    static constexpr bool value = T::value;
};

template <typename T>
void foo() requires (sizeof(T) == 1) || A<T>::value {}

int main()
{
    foo<char>();
}
```

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:13),source:'struct+Dummy+%7B%7D%3B%0Abool+operator%7C%7C(Dummy,+Dummy)+%7Breturn+true%3B%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++static+constexpr+bool+value+%3D+T::value%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+foo()+requires+(sizeof(T)+%3D%3D+1)+%7C%7C+A%3CT%3E::value+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo%3Cchar%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:53.82462686567165,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1000,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:32.68927413787708,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:9,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+10.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:67.31072586212292,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:46.17537313432835,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)</kbd>

Now Clang (10.0.0) starts to complain:

```
<source>:7:35: error: type 'char' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
    static constexpr bool value = T::value;
                                  ^
<source>:11:47: note: in instantiation of static data member 'A<char>::value' requested here
void foo() requires (sizeof(T) == 1) || A<T>::value {}
                                              ^
<source>:11:21: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
void foo() requires (sizeof(T) == 1) || A<T>::value {}
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:5: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'foo<char>' required here
    foo<char>();
    ^~~
<source>:15:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo<char>' requested here
```

GCC (trunk) has no problem with this code.

If `operator||` is in a namespace (and there's no `using namespace`), the code works.

Is it a Clang bug? Are there any workarounds, other than not having visible overloads of `||`?

Comment: Seems like an obvious clang bug to me.

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance, where is `T::value` defined? What would be `char::value`?

Comment: @Ripi2 Thing is, it shouldn't matter because the lhs of `||` is true. So the rhs should be discarded.

Comment: [Reported to Clang's bugzilla](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45589).

Comment: Freaky.  Looks like a bona fide compiler bug (congrats!).  `PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include" /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -fsanitize=undefined,null -std=c++2a HBC.cpp` using freshly compiled `clang version 10.0.0` (not my own heavily instrumented, somewhat bastardized, and slightly broken clang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug [was fixed](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45589), so the short-circuiting will work properly in Clang 11.